# Very simple Wordpress site with only one image never stops loading

Tags: wordpress, loops, load

http://180cashflowstrategies.com/

I did an Audit on this site using the Inspect Element feature of Google Chrome and there are many red flags involving caching and other issues. Something is causing this site to have a load loop. I am not sure what to do since there is only one image on my site and I have not done a whole lot of CSS editing. I have used this Divi theme on multiple other sites stored on my hosting account and none of the other ones have this issue.

Comment: The site loads fine for me. Maybe try clearing your cache/trying a different browser.

Comment: By the way, I only have four plugins in use, all of which are legit and widely-used. even after disabling all of them, the problem persists, so I know they aren't the issue.

Comment: I just cleared my cache and everything back to the "beginning of time" and I still get the never-ending spinning load wheel when I visit the site. Don't let me confuse you: the site content / database loads just fine. So you can always view the site within a second or so. But something in the background is causing the load wheel in the browser site tab to continue to spin after the site is displayed.

Comment: Site is loading fine for me.  Please try a different browser.  Are you using any browser extensions like Privacy Badger?  That makes a lot of sites break because not all assets are loaded.

Comment: No matter what I do it seems to do it in Chrome browser. I don't use extensions. In Safari the issue doesn't seem to be there.

Comment: looks fine for me in 4 different browsers + iPad